# mouseenter mouseleave within contents of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, mouseover, mouseenter

I'm trying to highlight elements within a iframe with no success. I've tried using mouseenter/mouseleave with no success. It does not fire.

```
$('#iframe').contents().mouseenter(function (e) {
    //var element = $(e.target);
    var element = $(this);

    $(element).addClass("highlight");
}).mouseleave(function (e) {
    $(element).removeClass("highlight");
});
```

I've had better success with mousemove however it highlights the parents as well which I don't want.

```
var prevElement;
$('#iframe').contents().find('html').on('mousedown', function (e) {
    e.stoppropagation()
    //e.preventDefault - did not work either
    var element = $(e.target);


    if (prevElement == null) {
        prevElement = element;
        element.addClass("edit-element-selector");
    }
    else {
        if (prevElement != element) {
            prevElement.removeClass("highlight");
            //prevElement.parents().removeClass("highlight"); did not work
            element.addClass("highlight");
        }   
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<iframe id="iframe" srcdoc="@Html.Raw(ViewBag.html)"></iframe>
```

Comment: got your html please?

Comment: @DomAdams Added html. Don't have much. It's literally just a iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem had 2 issues.

1. My css was wrong.

   > Wrong
   >
   > ```
   > .highlight :hover { 
   >   outline:4px solid #f00;
   > }
   > ```
   >
   > Right
   >
   > ```
   > .highlight {  
   >   outline:4px solid #f00; 
   > }
   > ```
2. Hover was bubbling up to the parents. Mouseenter and mouseleave worked however.

   ```
   var $iframe = $("#iframe").contents(); 

   $iframe.find('*').mouseover(function (e) {
       $(e.target).addClass('highlight');
   }).mouseout(function (e) {
       $(e.target).removeClass('highlight');
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The `css` rule for .hover is not visible in the context of the iframe.
Either use .css() to set style directly, add the css links or clone all styles in the main document into the iframe with jQuery.

Here is a working jfiddle which you should easily be able to copy.

http://jsfiddle.net/danmana/pMBw2/

Comment: Thanks but I still can't get it to work. Tt doesn't have anything to do css. Hovering only fires on the html element of the contents in the iframe but not any other element within.

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQuery Hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
    $(function () {
        var iContent = $('#iframe').contents();
        iContent.find('#id_username').val("New Value!");
        iContent.find('#id_username').hover(function () {
            $(this).css("border", "1px solid red");
        }, function () {
            $(this).css("border", "1px solid #c4c7cb");
        });
        console.log(iContent.find('#id_username'));
    });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwp4tksc/1/)

Sorry I guess I misunderstood the question.  Here is an updated fiddle changing the value of a text input and changing border color on hover.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. It tells me I'm hovering over the iframe but doesn't get the elements within.

Comment: I can't use find() because it is not restricted to an element.

I did try `$iframe.find('*').hover(function () {...` and it changes the border for the element but also the parents with I don't want.